# How to synchronize my port scanner so results would appear in order in which they were executed?

Tags: java, multithreading

I created a class which will try to scan ports of certain host.

The problem is that I get result in a random fashion or w/e finishes first.

How would I make sure that results will display in order I execute this port scan?

Test method (sorry Google):

```
public class SimplePortScanner
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for(int i = 78; i < 85; i++)
        {
            new Scanner("google.com", i).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Port scan method:

```
import java.net.*;

public class Scanner extends Thread
{
    private String address;
    private int port;

    Scanner(String address, int port)
    {
        super(address);
        this.address = address;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            SocketAddress sa = new InetSocketAddress(address, port);
            Socket socket = new Socket();
            socket.connect(sa, 2000);

            System.out.println("Port in use: " + port);

            socket.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Port not in use: " + port);
        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking of creating a thread number and save results in array in order they were executed (at least how I see it in my mind).

How to do this correctly? I'm just messing around with threading so sorry if I'm messing something up here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try java.util.concurrent

```
class Scanner implements Callable<Boolean> {
    ....

    @Override
    public Boolean call() {
        try {
            ....
            return true;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

ExecutorService ex = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
List<Scanner> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 78; i < 85; i++) {
    tasks.add(new Scanner("google.com", i));
}
List<Future<Boolean>> list = ex.invokeAll(tasks);
for(int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(i).get()) {
        System.out.printf("Port is in use: %d", tasks.get(i).port());
    } else {
        System.out.printf("Port is not in use: %d", tasks.get(i).port());
    }
}
// dont forget to shutdown executor
ex.shutdown();
```

Comment: +1 I generally add a shutdown in the sample codes - it can be a little confusing to see the JVM not exit when you have never used executors.

Comment: Correct, I'll add ex.shutdown()

Comment: Well, this is bit confusing to me because I never used anything you talk about :P

Comment: This is a chance to start learning java.util.concurrent. Actually you have no choice but start using it.   new Thread().start() is good for experiments only.